# Remove the multiple transactions and remain the first transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL Server 2005 for query, This my Query:

```
  select Transaction_Nr, Serial_Nr, Qty

  from TRANSACTION_TABLE
```

and I have an output like this:

```
    Transaction_Nr  |   Serial_Nr |    Qty
    -------------------------------------------
      40001         |    25001    |   2000  
      40002         |    25002    |   1500
      40003         |    25003    |   2700
      40004         |    25001    |   1500
      40005         |    25002    |   1000  
      40006         |    25008    |   3000
```

So how can I get only the first transaction_Nr for the Serial_Nr with multiple transactions and the output should be like this:

```
    Transaction_Nr  |   Serial_Nr |    Qty
    -------------------------------------------
      40001         |    25001    |   2000  
      40002         |    25002    |   1500
      40003         |    25003    |   2700
      40006         |    25008    |   3000
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please give detail like based on what you have to filter the multiple transaction.Do you want it by Qty ?

Comment: Is this just meant for a query or are you wanting to actually change the data in the table? And we're not doing anything with the data in the rows with later transaction numbers, correct? (other than discarding it completely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to assign suitable ordering information:

```
; With Ordered as (
    select Transaction_Nr,Serial_Nr,Qty,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Serial_Nr
                              ORDER BY Transaction_Nr) as rn
    from TRANSACTION_TABLE
)
select Transaction_Nr,Serial_Nr,Qty
from Ordered
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Who approved this edit... It is far less readable than before

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `So how can I get` which I interpretted to mean `select`:

Do a `group by "Serial_Nr"` to get the first `Transaction_Nr` for each `Serial_Nr`.
Then join those 'first serial numbers' back on to your table to get the desired rows.

```
SELECT y.* 
FROM (
        SELECT MIN("Transaction_Nr") AS "Transaction_Nr" 
        FROM "TRANSACTION_TABLE"
        GROUP BY "Serial_Nr"
     ) x
INNER JOIN "TRANSACTION_TABLE" y ON y."Transaction_Nr" = x."Transaction_Nr"
ORDER BY y."Transaction_Nr";
```

**edit:** @Damien_The_Unbeliever did basically the same thing, but used a CTE (Common table expression) rather than a self-join.

---

On the other hand, if you meant that after your query, the table should only contain the first row (based on serial number, i.e: delete the non-first rows):

```
DELETE FROM "TRANSACTION_TABLE"
USING (
          SELECT "Serial_Nr" AS "ser", 
                 MIN("Transaction_Nr") AS "trn"
          FROM "TRANSACTION_TABLE" 
          GROUP BY "Serial_Nr"
      ) x
WHERE "Serial_Nr" = x.ser
AND "Transaction_Nr" != x.trn;
```